# jQuery, How wait for one click event to be executed per element type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items where those items have their own content organized as lists. So far I have my jQuery expand the list to see the items for their lists. When clicking another item reverting the previously click item to be not expanded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).find("ul.bid_project").toggleClass("expanded" , 500);
        var list_items = $(this).find("ul.bid_project > li.bidding_content");

        if(!list_items.is(':visible')){
            list_items.show();
        } else {
            list_items.hide();
        }
        $(this).siblings().each(function() {
            if($(this).find("ul.bid_project").hasClass("expanded")) {
                $(this).find("ul.bid_project").toggleClass("expanded", 500);
                $(this).find("ul.bid_project > li.bidding_content").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My problem is that if I furiosily click on all of li that has the click eventhandler, they each run their own function to expand and check expansion. Is it possible to wait for only one click to be made then continue taking clicks other click on other nodes?

```
<ul id="bids" class="current_bids_container">
    <li>
        <ul class="bid_project">
            <p class="bidding_title">NYC MTA Above Grade Facility Hardening</p>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="bid_project">
            <p class="bidding_title">CONEY ISLAND HOSPITAL PARKING LOT</p>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding_content">• Lmao </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the second parameter of toggleClass(). I don’t think it can take suck parameter

Comment: They're using the jQuery UI library, which has an optional parameter for a duration - api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass

Comment: I love this CSS Tricks accordion. It works great with dt's and dd's and uses very clean jQuery code: https://codepen.io/css-tricks/full/LufJE

Answer (score 0):

I just created this Code Snippet below.

I think the solution is to remove the duration from the toggleClass Method and instead use CSS for animations.

Additionally I recommend to NOT place any non-"li"-elements inside an "ul"-element. Just a best practice. Another best practice is to use dash in CSS classnames instead of underscores ("bidding-content" instead of "bidding_content").

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // start website with all collapsed
 $("#bids li.bidding-content").hide();
    
    // expand / collapse on click
    $("li").click(function() {
        $(this).find("ul.bid-project").toggleClass("expanded");
        var list_items = $(this).find("ul.bid-project > li.bidding-content");

        if(!list_items.is(':visible')){
            list_items.show();
        } else {
            list_items.hide();
        }
        $(this).siblings().each(function() {
            if($(this).find("ul.bid-project").hasClass("expanded")) {
              $(this).find("ul.bid-project").toggleClass("expanded");
                $(this).find("ul.bid-project > li.bidding-content").hide();
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.bid-project {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-25px);
}

.expanded {
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<ul id="bids" class="current-bids-container">
    <li>
        <p class="bidding-title">NYC MTA Above Grade Facility Hardening</p>
        <ul class="bid-project">
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao  </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="bidding-title">CONEY ISLAND HOSPITAL PARKING LOT</p>
        <ul class="bid-project">
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
            <li class="bidding-content">• Lmao </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```